How can I get Intellisense working in Visual Studio Code while editing remote PHP plugin code on a Wordpress site via FTP?
I initially used WAMP to develop a custom plugin for Wordpress. Now that I've moved it to a hosted server, I use a VS Code FTP plugin to tweak the PHP code remotely. But now VS Code reports errors for all WP-specific functions, likely because it can't find the WP code in the local project. Is there a way to correct this?
